# C++ Can't include opencv2/core.hpp, even though it is in the include path. (Windows)

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors

I know its a common issue, but the usual fix is to add the path to the compiler's include path, and I already did that.

I ran into this problem and failed to fix it for a few hours now. I added the path to the highlighted file, you can even see it in the project's includes, but I still get that annoying error. 
Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks!!

[image: http://pasteboard.co/542vYzi48.png]

[image]

Comment: Did you check to make sure the file is actually at that location?

Comment: Yes, its there.

Comment: Do you get this error during compilation? Because if your project compiles successfully but error is still visible then you need to manually clear list of errors because eclipse has weird habit of not removing old errors / warnings.

Comment: Yeah, its during compilation. If I delete it and compile again it just shows up again.

Comment: Depending on project type, eclipse allows to configure separate include paths for C and C++ files. Are you sure that you've set paths correctly? What's inside of project buid settings?

Comment: I added a photo of the build settings.

Comment: How about using right slashes in these paths?

Comment: Still getting the same problem :(

Comment: Haha what a stupid problem. I included this class from a C file, and that threw the error. Oddly enough it wasn't in the c source file but here for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I included this class from a C file, and that threw the error. Oddly enough it wasn't in the c source file but here for some reason...

Simply changing it to a cpp file did the trick.